# TYPO3 action does not call

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and I have the problem, that my `addCommentAction` does not work/does not get called.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    "MyVendor.".$_EXTKEY,
    'commentForm',
    'Comment form'
); 

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MyVendor.'.$_EXTKEY,
    'commentForm',
    array('Comment' => 'form,addComment'),
    array('Comment' => 'form,addComment')
);



<f:form action="addComment" object="{newComment}" name="newComment" method="post" additionalParams="{showUid: userto}">
        <div style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div id="reviewStars-input">
                <f:form.hidden property="userto" value="{userto}"/>
                <f:form.radio property="rating" value="5" id="star-4"/>
                <label title="{f:translate(key: 'tx_fecomments_domain_model_comment.gorgeous')}" for="star-4"></label>
                <f:form.radio property="rating" value="4" id="star-3"/>
                <label title="{f:translate(key: 'tx_fecomments_domain_model_comment.good')}" for="star-3"></label>
                <f:form.radio property="rating" value="3" id="star-2"/>
                <label title="{f:translate(key: 'tx_fecomments_domain_model_comment.regular')}" for="star-2"></label>
                <f:form.radio property="rating" value="2" id="star-1"/>
                <label title="{f:translate(key: 'tx_fecomments_domain_model_comment.poor')}" for="star-1"></label>
                <f:form.radio property="rating" value="1" id="star-0"/>
                <label title="{f:translate(key: 'tx_fecomments_domain_model_comment.bad')}" for="star-0"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <f:form.textfield style="height: 100px;" property="text"/>
            <br>
            <f:form.submit class="btn btn-primary" value="{f:translate(key: 'tx_fecomments_domain_model_comment.send_comment')}"/>
        </div>

    </f:form>


    /**
     * @param \MyVendor\Fecomments\Domain\Model\Comment $newComment
     * @return bool
     */
    public function addCommentAction(\MyVendor\Fecomments\Domain\Model\Comment $newComment)
    {
        die(8979);
}
```

When I click "send form" nothing happens. I don't know why. Seems `addComment` action does not get called. In my other extension similar code works properly. When I click "send form" I have the next url `site.en/?showUid=1&tx_fecomments_commentform%5Baction%5D=addComment&tx_fecomments_commentform%5Bcontroller%5D=Comment&cHash=236d87f2ee987ddf7b5720ae5ddc029e`

It must work, so I don't know why it does not works. Help me please, I really don't have any ideas.

Also it's my Comment model:

```
namespace MyVendor\Fecomments\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;

class Comment extends AbstractEntity {
    /**
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $text = '';

    /**
     * user
     *
     * @var \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\User
     */
    protected $userfrom;

    /**
     * user
     *
     * @var \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\User
     */
    protected $userto;

    /**
     * @var int
     **/
    protected $crdate;

    /**
     * @var int
     **/
    protected $rating;

    /**
     * @param int $userfrom
     */
    public function setUserfrom($userfrom) {
        $this->userfrom = (int)$userfrom;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\User
     */
    public function getUserfrom() {
        return $this->userfrom;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $userto
     */
    public function setUserto($userto) {
        $this->userto = (int)$userto;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\User
     */
    public function getUserto() {
        return $this->userto;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $crdate
     */
    public function setCrdate($crdate) {
        $this->userto = (int)$crdate;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $rating
     */
    public function setRating($rating) {
        $this->rating = (int)$rating;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCrdate() {
        return $this->crdate;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRating() {
        return $this->rating;
    }

    /**
     * @param $text
     */
    public function setText($text) {
        $this->text = (string)$text;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getText() {
        return $this->text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add another snippet with your domain model. Maybe form submission fails due to validation problems.

Comment: I added snippet with my model. I hope for your help. Really I have not any ideas why it does't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Field 'rating' was not defined on my TCA.